# How can I install the latest kernel from kernel.org to Arch Linux ARM for Raspberry Pi 3 model B?

Tags: pi-3, kernel, archlinux

I am using Arch Linux on Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I want to install a newer kernel (currently I have `4.14.94-1-ARCH` kernel installed)

I have downloaded and compiled the mainline kernel 5.0-rc5, which took many hours.

But somehow I am confused with the traditional compilation and installation of the mainline kernel on Raspberry Pi 3 model B.

How can I do that?

Comment: Follow the instructions at https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux - in the *Documentation* folder - it's fully documented